# django get latest release QuerySet

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

```py
class Release(models.Model):
    version = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    project = models.ForeignKey('projects.Project', related_name='releases', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=1, null=1)


class Project(models.Model):
    # pass


def getObjects():
    releases = []
    for project in Project.objects.all():
        if project.releases.all():
            releases.append(project.releases.all().order_by('-version')[0])
    return releases
```

is it possible to get a queryset of latest releases of each project if it has release? sorry I literally have no idea how to write the queryset.

---

I am sorry that I posted the wrong model, project field is meant to be on Release model, just a copy and paste issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this in a single query, you will need to combine `annotate` and `filter` together.

The method is to annotate each object with the highest version for each project related to the release. So we use a double-underscore through relation of `project__releases__version`. This gets the project related to each release, gets all of the related releases to that project and thus all of the versions.

We can apply `Max` to that field to get the highest one. Once we know what the latest version is, we can simply filter the queryset for that value using an `F()` object, which gets the field value.

```py
from django.db.models import Max, F

Release.objects.annotate(
      latest_for_project=Max(project__releases__version)
   ).filter(
      latest_for_project=F('release')
   )
```

Comment: thanks, this actually inspire me to add a `BooleanField` to `Release` model, which turn previous to `False` when new one is created, will save much more work.

Comment: Nice idea, keeps things more obvious

Answer (score 1):

You have to set relation properly. You should not connect `Project` to `Project`, if you want to have relation with `Release` :)
It is much better to use direct relationship or model's method. Then you can easier use it anywhere outside.

```
class Release(models.Model):
    version = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    project = models.ForeignKey('projects.Project', related_name='releases', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=1, null=1)


class Project(models.Model):
    # project fields

    def latest_release(self):
        return self.releases.order_by('-version').first()
```

Then in fuction (or shell):

```
def get_latest_releases():

    releases = []
    for project in Project.objects.all():
        if project.latest_release():
            releases.append(project.latest_release())
    return releases
```

Comment: thanks very much for you help, sorry that I posted the wrong model, however I needed a queryset solution for further usage.